# exceuting windows script through php

Tags: php, windows, exec, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to execute a windows script through php in wamp.
When I try the command below:
`exec('"C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe" http://google.com C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.20-1/apache2/htdocs/google.pdf');`
it works fine but if I try to execute as below it does not work
`$path_to = 'C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.20-1/apache2/htdocs/google.pdf';
    $path_from = 'http://google.com';
exec("'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe' $path_from $path_to");`

I need the link and the path  as variables , that's why I am trying that kind of code.

Comment: Try doing `echo "'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe' $path_from $path_to";` and see what it outputs

Comment: 'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe' http://google.com C:/Bitnami/wampstack-7.1.20-1/apache2/htdocs/google.pdf

Comment: Can you try `exec("C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe $path_from $path_to");`?

Comment: In your second example the variables `$path_from` and `$path_to` are not enclosed with double quotes and are likely failing.

Comment: Already tried that Bojan

Comment: Not working even with your suggestion Dave